# how should i write this query? if there are tables customer, order, and product then (online shopping)

Tags: sql-server

if there are tables customer, order, and product then (online shopping)

```
1) all customers who have purchased more than one products in same order
2) top 10 customers who have spent most money
```

if there are doctors, patients and appointments then (hospital management)

```
1) all patients who have been diagnosed by more than one doctors
2) top 10 patients who have most appointments
```

if there are students, teachers and courses (school management system)

```
1) all students who have taken more than one course from same teacher
2) top 10 students with respect to scores
```

Comment: Please show what you've tried to do so far. Don't just ask other people to write your code for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'll do first one :

schema should be something like this customer--> orders-->products

```
   1. select *,count(*) from customers c join order o on c.order_id=o.orders_id join products p on 
    p.product_id=c.product_id where count(*)>1 group by c.order_id,p.product_id


2.select top 10 from customers order by spent_money desc
```

Comment: plz answer other two also its very very urgent please

Comment: you could jus map above query with other required, i'm not sure if it works :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT patients, doctors FROM hospital_management GROUP BY patients,doctors HAVING COUNT(doctors) > 1

SELECT TOP 10 FROM hospital_management ORDER BY appointments DESC
```